# rxjs - searching in observables

Tags: search, rxjs

I am trying to implement a simple search scheme to search for values in one observable from another observable. The `buildLookup` function below builds a lookup table using values from an observable:

```
// Build lookup table from an observable. 
// Returns a promise
function buildLookup(obs, keyName, valName) {
    const map = new Map();
    obs.subscribe((obj) => map.set(obj[keyName], obj[valName]));

    // use concat to force wait until `obs` is complete
    return obs.concat(Observable.from([map])).toPromise();
}
```

Then I have another function this uses the result of this function (a promise):

```
// Lookup in a previously built lookup table.
function lookup(source, prom, keyName, fieldName) {
    return source.map((obj) => {
        const prom2 = prom.then((map) => {
            return lodash.assign({}, obj, { [fieldName]: map.get(String(obj[keyName])) });
        });
        return Observable.fromPromise(prom2);
    })
    .flatMap((x) => x);
}
```

For some reason, this implementation does not work, and *every other* lookup seems to fail. Could you someone guide me on:

- what is wrong with this code, and
- whether there is a better way to implement something like this?

Thanks a bunch in advance for your help!

I am attaching my test code below:

```
"use strict";
const lodash = require("lodash");
const rxjs = require("rxjs");
const chai = require("chai");

const Observable = rxjs.Observable;
const assert = chai.assert;
const assign = lodash.assign;

describe("search", () => {
    it("simple search", (done) => {
        let nextId = 1, nextId2 = 1;
        const sourceObs = Observable.interval(5).take(5).map((i) => {
            const id = nextId++;
            return { id: `${id}` };
        });

        const searchableObs = Observable.interval(5).take(5).map((i) => {
            const id = nextId2++;
            return Observable.from([
                { id: `${id}`, code: "square", val: id * id },
            ]);
        }).flatMap((x) => x);


        const results = [];
        const verifyNext = (x) => {
            assert.isDefined(x);
            results.push(x);
        };
        const verifyErr = (err) => done(err);
        const verifyComplete = () => {
            assert.equal(results.length, 5);
            try {
                results.forEach((r) => {
                    console.log(r);
                    // assert.equal(r.val, r.id*r.id);  <== *** fails ***
                });
            } catch (err) {
                done(err);
            }
            done();
        };

        // main
        const lookupTbl = buildLookup(searchableObs, "id", "val"); // promise that returns a map
        lookup(sourceObs,  lookupTbl, "id", "val")
            .subscribe(verifyNext, verifyErr, verifyComplete)
            ;
    });

});


// output
// { id: '1', val: 1 }
// { id: '2', val: undefined }
// { id: '3', val: 9 }
// { id: '4', val: undefined }
// { id: '5', val: 25 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a bunch of things to address here.

The main issue is that you are doing side-effects in your `sourceObs` and `searchableObs` observables, and it is not published, so the side-effects happen multiple times because you subscribe multiple times, giving you a wrong map entirely. For instance, I get maps like:

`{"1" => 1, "4" => 16, "7" => 49, "12" => 144}`

But you are doing something so trivial that you should really **not** use mutable variables.

---

To solve this, here is how you can create the proper observables:

```js
const sourceObs = Rx.Observable.range(1, 5).map(i => ({ id: `${i}` }));

const searchableObs = Rx.Observable.range(1, 5).map(i =>
  ({ id: `${i}`, code: "square", val: i * i })
);
```

There is no reason to use a variable since `range` returns the numbers 1, 2, ...
And your use of `o.map(_ => Rx.Observable.from(...)).concatMap(e => e)` is really just the same as `o`...

---

While I'm here, this is a simplified version of your correct but clumsy functions:

```js
// so buildLookup just needs to return a map once it's finished populating it
function buildLookup(obs, keyName, valName) {
  // following your style here, though this could be done using `scan`
  const map = new Map();
  obs.subscribe((obj) => map.set(obj[keyName], obj[valName]));
  // instead of your promise, I just wait for `obs` to complete and return `map` as an observable element
  return obs.ignoreElements().concat(Rx.Observable.of(map));
}

// and lookup just needs to wait for the map, and then populate fields in the object    
function lookup(source, prom, keyName, fieldName) {
  return prom
    .concatMap(map => source.map(obj => ({ obj: obj, map: map })))
    .map(({ obj, map }) => lodash.assign({}, obj, { [fieldName]: map.get(String(obj[keyName])) }))
  ;
}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Thank you @Ptival, very helpful.